# Automating the extraction of text from images

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, text-extraction

I have 500 folders in AWS S3 Bucket. In each of those folders, there are 2 to 3 images. How do I apply Textract on each of those images and extract the complete text(all text concatenated) using node js? I wrote the following code to get the S3 Object :

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const config = require('./config.js');
(async function(){
    aws.config.setPromisesDependency();
    try{
        aws.config.update({
            accessKeyId: config.accessKeyId,
            secretAccessKey: config.secretAccessKey,
            region: config.awsRegion
        });
        const s3 = new aws.S3();
        const response = await s3.listObjectsV2({
            Bucket : '<Bucket Name>',
            Prefix : '<Prefix>'

        }).promise();
        console.log(response);
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        console.log('our err.',e);
    }
    
})();
```

How do I loop through the sub folders and images present in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may either:

- Use S3 API to list and loop through all images, apply text extraction for each of them
- Use S3 inventory to loop through all images and do the same

For new files, you can set up a Lambda function and S3 `PUT` trigger to automatically apply text detection to new files.

Comment: I have edited my question to update on what I have done. How do I move forward?

Comment: Use the result of `S3.listObjectV2` then use `Textract.detectDocumentText` for each object.